# Using Emoji in my own iOS app?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, emoji

I’m developing my own iOS app which receives notifications sent from Parse. I want to use Emoji in my notification while sending it from Parse,  and I simply copy & paste the Emoji I need from the link below:
http://getemoji.com/
My question is : am I allowed to use Emoji directly in my own iOS app/notification? Is there any terms of usage for Emoji? Thank you in advance!